# Shisui's Mangekyo Sharingan Recharge Period

Tags: naruto

According to Narutopedia for Shisui's MS ability Kotoamatsukami...

> Itachi noted that the dōjutsu required at least a decade before it could be used again.

Does this limitation apply to Shisui, or does it just apply to those that took his eyes (Danzo and Itachi)? Because if this applied to him, then he's not as OP as everyone thinks he is. Plus how would he know it has a recharge period of 10 years?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your two questions

1. It was never mentioned if Shisui had to wait for a decade to use it, so we don't know if this rule applies to him. If he did have to wait for 10 years, he's **very underpowered**. I don't think it applied to him because everyone knew about his ability and if that rule applied to him, he'd have used the ability for a maximum of 2 or 3 times (not possible, 2 is max because 2 eyes), many people wouldn't know about it.
2. Itachi said that Kotoamatsukami takes 10 years to recharge for those who don't have Hashirama's cells.
3. There are 2 ways he could know the recharge period.

   - Shisui told him. That would mean, this drawback would apply to him too. But its very unlikely that he had the Mangekyo for over 10 years. So he himself wouldn't know about the recharge period.
   - He used Kotoamatsukami just after Shisui died and he knew the period was 10 years because it activated after 10 years in the war. This is dumb. I'm dumb. Itachi is smart. He wouldn't gamble.
   - The third way, I know I said two but bear with me. **THIS IS A PLOT HOLE.** Every anime has one. Itachi just couldn't know the recharge time.

**THOUGHTS**

How does Hashirama's cells affect the eyes? If we give the eye which has been used for Kotoamatsukami to say Danzo/Yamato (someone who has his cells), would the eyes recharge instantly?

Comment: I think the second way deserves far more credit than you give it. Itachi using it for some purpose without knowing the recharge time is very likely. Little was known about Mangekyou back then. Shisui probably could use it frequently, much like Himself, Obito and Sasuke were freely using theirs. The only Transplant example is Danzo, and he kept his very secret, So Itachi had nothing to go on. Him finding out by experimentation is the only reasonable way. He did also gamble on Sasuke staying on the side of the leaf village, which failed twice (Orochimaru and Tobi)

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't be the case for Shisui.

1. It makes no sense why he would be the ONLY person to have a limitation on his ability, especially since he only has one (that we know about) while everyone else has two.
2. If we use the manga like [BattleofAnime shisue uchiha's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/40509/2516) pointed out, that's an even bigger plot hole since Shisui used it during his fight and that half Hyuga with one Byakugan, which was way shorter than 10 years, plus probably at least one other time prior for him to even know what his ability was. I don't think he personally had a cooldown period, just the normal drawbacks like large Chakra use and going blind. The 10-year cooldown is probably just for other people who take his eyes.

Comment: A few notes about the first point, a Mangekyo awakening 1 ability shared by both eyes isn't unique to Shisui, Obito's eyes both possess Kamui. This means we know an equal number of Uchiha who had 2 abilities as we know who had 1. Sasuke and Itachi having 2 whereas Obito and Shisui have 1. The other Mangekyo wielders' abilities are not explored so whether they have 1 or 2 is up in the air. Another thing about the limitations, non-Uchiha who use the eyes will generally find it more taxing, Kakashi is left bedridden after a few uses of Kamui while Obito uses it as easily as he breathes

Answer (score 0):

No way it'll take shisui every 10 yrs to activate it. If you remember he used it on hidden mist ninjas and still planned on using it on Fugaku. I know it wasn't the same time but it can't be said the time with the hidden mist ninjas and Fugaku are 10 yrs apart. I mean how old was Shisui anyway

And you saying he could defeat kaguya with it is a serious cap...... The otsutsuki clan are immunity to anything genjutsu related....so next make enough research and be sure to have facts backing up your caps............

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! Please be aware that this is a strict Q&A site, not a discussion forum; answers are for answering the question, not for criticising other answers. If it doesn't take Shisui ten years to recharge his Mangekyo Sharingan, then how long *does* it take him?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it does take Shisui ten years to recharge. It is stated in Episode 201 of the anime that it would take Shisui ten years to recharge when they were talking about overthrowing the Leaf Village.

But is he underpowered? No, he is not. His Mangekyo Sharingan could be used to kill Kaguya if desired. The fact that it's so powerful is why he can only use it once every ten years. Plus, he's a very strong ninja.

Comment: Only Itachi states that the Crow can use it once every 10 years. Danzo used it during the kage meeting and still was making plans later that day  to use it on Tobi. Being in a person, as well as having Hashirama's cells sped up the recharge rate significantly. Shisui, being the original owner, would have a fast recharge time as well, but how long he would have to wait specifically was never mentioned.

Comment: No like i said it is stated that shisue can use it only ounce every ten years and considering its power its completley beleivable. its the most powerful genjutsu and dojustsu around because of what it can do. so the two most powerful tools in all of anime are the death note and shisues EMS.

Comment: Get your facts right. Its no where mentioned in EP201. It was not mentioned by Shisui anywhere.